# Scroll bar not showing up in webpage

Tags: html, css

Im helping a friend with a website and when i resize the browser windows the scroll bar on the right side is not showing up. Is there a fix for this or a way to work around it?

here is the site page im working on

## Fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your whole web-page is wrapped inside a DIV with the ID "style" like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="style">
        your web-page
    <div>
</body>
```

The CSS for this DIV is:

```
#style {
    background: url(http://upupandfly.com/envie/images/bg_style.PNG) no-repeat;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

This CSS is causing the problem. You have to either get rid of the fixed positioning, or just try to remove that DIV...

Comment: You overlooked the fact that <html> has position:fixed associated with it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `div#style` and `html` elements are `position:fixed`, try removing these declarations, and your problem will cease to exist (promise!)